# HAProxy errors configuration

Tags: haproxy

I have problems with my configuration HaProxy :

```
frontend http-in
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    #option httplog
    acl site1 hdr(host) -i http://XX.XX.XX.12/games/
    acl site2 hdr(host) -i http://XX.XX.XX.12/videos/
    use_backend backend1 if site1
    use_backend backend2 if site2

 backend backend1
    mode http
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1
    server site1 10.11.12.10:80 maxconn 32

 backend backend2
    mode http
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1
    server site2 10.11.12.2:80 maxconn 32
```

Can you help me, I think I have problem with `if` because when I test with only IP, the system is functional.

Comment: Please take time to format your question properly.

Comment: I don't see an actual question or error message here...

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is using hdr(host) in your ACL.  You could try it with the path option and it should work.

```
acl site1 path /games
use_backend backend1 if site1

acl site2 path /videos
use_backend backend2 if site2
```